# How does PHP 'records' sessions?

Tags: php, session

I understand how sessions work in PHP, but I can't understand what the documentation is trying to say with this note:

> **Note:**
>
> Please note when working with sessions that a record of a session is not created until a variable has been registered using the session_register() function or by adding a new key to the $_SESSION superglobal array. This holds true regardless of if a session has been started using the session_start() function.

Link: http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php

A file is created for each session even if there's no data associated with the session, for example adding a key/value to the $_SESSION array. So what does the documentation means that a record is not created for a session until this happens?

Comment: `A file is created for each session even if there's no data associated with the session` are you sure about that?

Comment: @Pekka, yes: http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.installation.php

Comment: Ah, that seems like a contradiction then. Perhaps a bug in the documentation, wouldn't be the first

Comment: @Pekka웃 Perhaps, but I'm glad I'm not the only one noticing the contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

in my testing, file has been created even the php script just have one column

```
<?php 
session_start();
?>
```

so this may be a mistake in the doc.